# How can I perform an action (show a popover) when an NSTokenField becomes first responder?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstokenfield

I'm trying to subclass `NSTokenField` to show an `NSPopover` or a menu with some options once the control gets the focus. Unfortunately after a couple of days of tentatives I'm starting to think that it's not possible.

Here is what I have tried so far:

- The `-textDidBeginEditing` and `-controlTextDidBeginEditing` are useless because they get called only after the user type the first letter. I need something that gets fired on focus.
- Overriding `-becomeFirstResponder` and `-resignFirstResponder` to show and hide the menu or popover are no use either. The tokenfield apparently passes the first responder status to a private view (`NSTokenFieldView`) so `-resignFirsttResponder` gets called right after `-becomeFirstReponder` closing the menu or popover immediately.
- I tried watching for the value of `-currentEditor` before dismissing the menu in `-resignFirstResponder`. The `-currentEditor` should be non-nil when the control is in edit mode but unfortunately its value is set only after `-resignFirstResponder` in the tokenfield is called and once again the menu gets closed immediately.
- I tried subclassing the `NSTokenFieldCell` and override its `-editWithFrame:` and `-selectWithFrame:` methods but the tokenfield with my custom `NSTokenFieldCell` is not shown at all and no error or exception are reported.

Any idea on how to do this? Has anyone done it?

Comment: How exactly do you need to dismiss the popover? You can certainly show it in acceptsFirstResponder or becomeFirstResponder, but how you dismiss it depends on what happens next in the work flow. Could you dismiss it in one of the text editing delegate methods once you start entering text.

Comment: Yes that worked beautifully! Now I show the popover on `-becomeFirstResponder` and close it on `-textDidEndEditing`. I don't know why I didn't think of it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This works. I did it by observing the `firstResponder` property of the parent window. If the token field *or any of its contained `NSResponder`s* become first responder, you show the popover.

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    [ self.window addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"firstResponder" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil ] ;
}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ( object == self.window && [ keyPath isEqualToString:@"firstResponder" ] )
    {
        NSResponder * responder = [ change valueForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey ] ;

        while ( NULL != responder )
        {
            if ( responder == self.tokenField )
            {
                // show popover (if not showing)
                NSLog(@"Show popover!\n") ;
                return ;
            }
            responder = responder.nextResponder ;
        }

        NSLog(@"Hide popover!\n") ;
    }
    else
    {
        [ super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context ] ;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: You'll have to "debounce" the _show popover_ signal--it may get called multiple times per "show" message. I did it without subclassing--the observation machinery is on the AppDelegate/window owner, but you could easily modify this to work in a custom subclass of NSTokenField

Comment: Thanks I solved used the approach from the comment on the main post.